# Uploading static zipfile using paperclip fails with Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError for filename.zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, zip

I am creating zipfiles in temp folder but i am not able to upload a static zipfile to s3.It fails with error Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError for myfilename.zip.Here is my code

**controller**

```
def create_zipfile
     file = File.join(Rails.root, "public/temp_download/invoices_#{timer}.zip")
     Zip::Archive.open(file, Zip::CREATE) do |ar|
     Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/temp_download/invoices_#{timer}/*").each do |path|
     ar.add_file(path.split('/').last, path) # add_file(<entry name>, <source path>)
     end
  end
  upload(pfile)
end

def upload(filename)
     invoice_upload = InvoiceUpload.new
     invoice_upload.invoice =  filename
     invoice_upload.save
end
```

**model**

```
class InvoiceUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
                      has_attached_file :invoice,
                      :storage => :s3,
                      :url     => 's3_domain_url',
                      :s3_host_alias  => '***'
                      :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'), 
                      :path => "/invoices/:style/:id_:filename"
end
```

Comment: Please share `InvoiceUpload` class.

Comment: just edited my post with InvoiceUpload class thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the upload method as below:

```
def upload(filename)
     invoice_upload = InvoiceUpload.new
     invoice_upload.invoice =  Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(filename)
     invoice_upload.save
end
```

Also, `upload(pfile)` should be `upload(file)` in `create_zipfile` as there is no variable named `pfile` in your code.